# Adding sensors on Intel Atom through GPIO

Tags: lcd, led, intel-atom, sensors

I am building a portable medical kit on Intel Atom N240 series, loaded with FC 11.

I am adding sensors (spirometer oximeter) through GPIO, (using RS 232, spi. USB is also an option). I have loaded the module needed to bring GPIO to userspace and I can now set each pin as input/output, the logical values at these pins.

All this I am able to do from both kernel space and user space (writing to `/sys/class/gpio` folders).

Initially I would like to start of by adding an LCD or LED display, although there is LVDS interface, I would like to use GPIO  since I want to add others sensors through GPIO.

Where shall I start from? There quite a few tutorials on this topics for ARM but none for Intel Atom. If one exists, can you please tell me where it is?

Comment: This sounds pretty cool what you are doing, but, is there a reason you are going x86/Atom? ... ARM/embedded would be much more fit for purpose when you don't need a full blown console and will have other benefits - especially when portable such as much longer battery life

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Well,portable kit is just the first step , I want to build a database with the data collected and send it through wireless/ wired network to civic authorities. Basically, this kit is meant for use in place where there is lack of medical services, this is my term project.I am also supposed to reduce memory footprint of OS loaded the idea is to learn how to do these things rather than sticking to the easiest platform available which are efficient implicitly

Comment: @WilliamHilsum I think he meant to notify you ;)

Comment: @SharanGowda - You will probably get much much lower memory on an ARM, however, this is a cool project and good luck - sorry I can't actually help with a solution!